# How can I get xpath query(hidden) coming from response in Jmeter?

Tags: xpath, jmeter

That's a response, traced from Fiddler. Need to grab PCAIId for and re-user later in jmeter script.

```
</xs:complexType>
  <xs:unique name="Constraint1" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
    <xs:selector xpath=".//PolicyChange.policychangeaoi" />
     <xs:field xpath="**PCAOIId**" />
    </xs:unique>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your "piece" of response I can only suggest using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), the relevant Regular Expression would be something like `<xs:field xpath="(.+?)" />`

[image]

---

A better idea would be going for [XPath2 Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor) (available since [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5)), however it is quite hard to come up with the exact configuration without seeing the full response.